# Get User Activities for Guilds on Discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is it possible to get the message and reaction count (=user activities) from a user on a guild when he authorizes me via OAuth2? Ideally, I want to know this from all the guilds a user is in. I couldn't see such a possibility via the API.

The only way I can imagine it can be achieved is by adding bots to the respective guilds which are collecting this information via events (on message, on reaction, etc.)

Has anybody done similar things already? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you add more details, you want to get a guild member activities without using a bot ? Like with the api ?

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. I would like to get the rights from the user via OAuth2 and then want to load his activities (=messages and reactions) on his guilds. Like retrieving a list of his guilds (https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guilds) but with a lot more information to the user on the guilds.

Comment: Do you agree that with a bot this would be possible? But this bot has to be added to all the guilds and therefore allowed by the guild owner. I want to achieve the same by only requesting permissions from the user via the API. But I think this is not possible. What do you say?

Comment: Bots cannot get "counts" of a user, the closest thing would be a guild count

Comment: The bot could watch/react to all the incoming messages and reactions from the time it was added to the guild and can then keep track of these data. That was my thought.